# UITextField embedded in a UIView not responding to touch events

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield

Why does a `UITextField` not respond to touch events when embedded in a `UIView` (which itself is embedded in the original view controller's main `UIView`)?

Here's the code:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [UIView new];

    UIView *positionalView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 280, 100)];

    UITextField *usernameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 50)];
    usernameField.placeholder = @"Full Name";
    usernameField.delegate = self;
    [usernameField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    [positionalView addSubview:usernameField];

    UITextField *passwordField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 50)];
    passwordField.placeholder = @"Password";
    passwordField.delegate = self;
    [passwordField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    [positionalView addSubview:passwordField];

    [self.view addSubview:positionalView];
}
```

Finding it difficult to understand this behavior as the above code works fine, if I simply remove the `positionalView` and add the text fields directly to the main self.view.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Both UITextField have same x, y, width & height coordinates?

Answer (score 5):

You create a local variable named `positionalView`, but add the text fields to a property named `positionalView`. These are not the same variables.

Comment: Thanks Leo. If this happened to be a typo in the code example (oops! fixed!), is there any other explanation to the view behaviour?

Comment: What I saw in the code was adding one view on top of another, causing the text field to have a view above it, and thus not receiving events.

Answer (score -1):

The parent UIView's size is zero, pin the top, bottom, left and right constraints of the UITextField to the parent view so the parent view's size is the size of the UITextField, or set the frame of the parent UIView so that it has a size that is not zero.

Check the Debug View Hierarchy debug tool to check!

Answer (score -2):

You need `bringSubviewToFront:`:

```
[positionalView addSubview:usernameField];
[positionalView bringSubviewToFront:usernameField];
```

Same for passwordField and positionalView

Comment: Any comments why downvote? This is common problem, when one view covers textfield and it can't respond on touches. `addSubview` adds view to back. To make textfield respond to touches you need bring it to front.